# Special case nodal analysis

Tags: kirchhoffs-laws, nodal-analysis

[image]

I tried to calculate, but I'm quite confused to go further. The calculations can be seen in the image itself.

This is a special case, nodal analysis with special dependent voltage source branch.

How to approach further in this problem?

Comment: Write down as many true equations as you can.  Assign variables (and direction) to unknown currents.

Comment: Let's label the node with the two current sources attached as \$v_1\$ and the node with the \$2\:\text{k}\Omega\$ and \$6\:\text{k}\Omega\$ resistors attached as \$v_2\$. Then do you not see that \$i_x=\frac{v_o-v_2}{2\:\text{k}\Omega}\$? This factors into the equation you wrote, with \$v_1=v_2+4\:\text{k}\Omega\cdot i_x\$, does it not?

Comment: So using a supernode approach (you don't have to, but let's go there), this results in just two equations: (1) \$\frac{v_2+4\:\text{k}\Omega\,\cdot\,\frac{v_o\,-\,v_2}{2\:\text{k}\Omega}}{3\:\text{k}\Omega}+2\:\text{mA}+\frac{v_2}{2\:\text{k}\Omega}+\frac{v_2}{6\:\text{k}\Omega}=8\:\text{mA}+\frac{v_o}{2\:\text{k}\Omega}\$ and (2) \$\frac{v_o}{1\:\text{k}\Omega}+\frac{v_o}{2\:\text{k}\Omega}=2\:\text{mA}+\frac{v_2}{2\:\text{k}\Omega}\$. These solve out as \$v_2=14.8571428571429\:\text{V}\$ and \$v_o=6.28571428571429\:\text{V}\$. That's consistent with your provided answer.

Answer (score 2):

Not nodal analysis, as such, but step by step:[image]Nodel

You can find mesh current and loop voltage approaches described elsewhere online. You should carefully choose one or the other depending on the problem. It's important to understand both to understand the analysis techniques.

Now for the good news: you'll never need to use either approach as a design engineer. I never have in 60 (yes 60) years. There must be problems that do. My college course that showed how-to in a lecture session presented an overnight Fortran analysis result from prof (Dennis Fermental) but we students weren't asked to do so - just shown how. Problems like these aren't ones you'd pose for yourself in the course of a design, but some you'd rarely deal with IRL.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, How do you convert the 8 A into 6 A, I didn't understand the conversion

Comment: The two current sources in the original problem put 6 ma into the node they connect to. Changing the connection of the 2 ma source makes it a different circuit but the current into the node is still 6 ma and the current from the Vo- node is still 8 ma.